# DelegateCommand inside Listview with UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-controls

Is there any method to use my `DelegateCommand` inside my `ListView` with `UserControl`:

UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App13.UserControls.ItemTemplateControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App13"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
        <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding OpenCommand"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There is no error in my `MainViewModel`. There is error in Binding.
I can easily use `OpenCommand` in `MainPage` xaml using this code:

```
 d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

<Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding OpenCommand"/>
```

How can I bind `OpenCommnad` to my UserControl? 
Sorry for my English and thanks in advance!

This is my ListView:

```
 <ListView x:Name="peopleListBox">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                            <UserControls:ItemTemplateControl/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: You need to set the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` to be `MainViewModel`

Comment: I set that: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`

Answer (score 0):

In the construction of your UserControl do

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

`d:DataContext` is just the Design time DataContext setting which is not applied at runtime.

Comment: Yes it works when i put my UserControl outside my ListView. In my case this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

By the name of it, `DesignInstance` is meant for design-time and not run-time.

In MVVM there are two approches of setting your `ViewModel`.

*ViewFirst* or *ViewModelFirst* -  depending wether you build your app top down or bottom up.

for *ViewFirst* You can set your `DataContext` from your xaml :

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App13.UserControls.ItemTemplateControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App13"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.DataContext>
     <local:MainViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

     <!-- Rest of your implementation ... -->  

</UserControl>
```

For *ViewModelFirst*, set it in your code behind (usually done from View's constructor)

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

If you want to bind a property from your viewModel to an Item in your `ListBox`, bind your button inside the `UserControl` as follows:

```
        <Button Content="Click" 
            Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
            />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it works when i put my UserControl outside my ListView. In my case this code doesn't work

Comment: @RüstəmRövşənKərimov Do you have a ListBox of UserControl's? post the code of your `ListBox` it would be much easier to help you